# Webservice 4 classes and 1 showing on consumer

Tags: c#, web-services

i have a webservice running, in this webservice i have added a class file (Class.cs)
in this file there are 4 classes, when the client(consumer) connects to the webservice i can only see 1 class of the 4. i have re-published the webservice many times, and i have also updated the webreference many times. i dont understand what i going wrong.
here is the content of the class file:

```
public class AnsweredQ
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public AnsweredQ() { }

    public AnsweredQ(string _Question, string _Answer)
    {
        Question = _Question;
        Answer = _Answer;
    }
}
public class BadlyAnsweredQ
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
    public string BadAnswer { get; set; }

    public BadlyAnsweredQ() { }

    public BadlyAnsweredQ(string _Question, string[] _Options, string _BadAnswer)
    {
        Question = _Question;
        Options = _Options;
        BadAnswer = _BadAnswer;
    }
}
public class UnAnsweredQ
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string[] Options { get; set; }

    public UnAnsweredQ() { }

    public UnAnsweredQ(string _Question, string[] _Options)
    {
        Question = _Question;
        Options = _Options;
    }
}
public class TrialNoobs
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrialDate { get; set; }
    public bool Expired { get; set; }

    public TrialNoobs() { }

    public TrialNoobs(string _User, DateTime _TrialDate, bool _Expired)
    {
        User = _User;
        TrialDate = _TrialDate;
        Expired = _Expired;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try clean solution. Right click on your colution and from context menu choose "Clean Solution". It might help.

Comment: Tried it just now, didnt help.